# JDBC node module not working in other systems

Tags: java, linux, node.js, jdbc

I have used `npm install jdbc` to install the `jdbc` node module in my 32 bit `Linux` OS. I've written a node code :

```
var jdbc = new ( require('jdbc') );

var config = {
  libpath: __dirname + 'path/to/jdbc.jar',
  drivername: 'cs.jdbc.driver.CompositeDriver',
  url: connectionurl,
  // optionally   
  user: username,
  password: password,
};

app.get('/jdbctry', function (req, res) {
   jdbc.initialize(config, function(err, res) {
   if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   }
});

var genericQueryHandler = function(err, results) {
if (err) {
 console.log(err);
} else if (results) {
  console.log(results);
}

jdbc.close(function(err) {
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
} else {
  console.log("Connection closed successfully!");
}
});

};

jdbc.open(function(err, conn) {
 if (conn) {
// SELECT statements are called with executeQuery 
jdbc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table", genericQueryHandler);
 }
});
});
```

I've run it in my local system and it works perfectly fine.

But my requirement is to run it in another 32 bit `Linux` machine with no access to the Internet. I moved the code and the `jdbc` module to the other system, and tried running it, I get the following error :

```
Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                           ^  
Error: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 at Error (native)
 at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
 at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
 at require (module.js:384:17)
 at Object.<anonymous (/common/node_modules/jdbc/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:10:16)
 at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this "java"?  It looks like "javascript" to me!

Comment: @StephenC He is using a node.js JDBC module that uses the JVM to access JDBC drivers.

Comment: Are you sure that Java is even installed on that other box (the one that throws the exception)?

Comment: @defectus I've checked the JAVA_HOME variable. jdk is there in the other box also.